# How add custom fields to django-serializer dynamically?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to write a simple CRUD application. I have several pretty similar model classes and one serializer:

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    queryset = None
    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls, queryset, context_class, **kwargs):
        _srlz = cls()
        _srlz.Meta.model = context_class
        _srlz.Meta.fields = '__all__'
        _srlz.queryset = queryset
        _srlz = cls(_srlz.queryset, **kwargs)
        return _srlz
    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = ''
```

so I can serialize my classes, calling initialize function like this:

```
_q = Foo.objects.all()
_srlz = TestModelSerializer.initialize(_q, Foo, many = True)

_q2 = Bar.objects.all()
_srlz2 = TestModelSerializer.initialize(_q2, Bar, many = True)
```

and so on.

But I have faced to one problem. Sometimes my classes are in hard One-to-Many relation (composition):

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

When I serialize Foo class I want to serialize a list of related Bar classes as well and nest result data to Foo's serializer data.
I am not intended to write custom serializer for each of these classes but instead try to implement some generic approach.

I decided to make some experiments and finally create an interface that provides me several methods for my collection items:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = iCollection
    pass
```

Now when instantiate a serializer I can get all fields of my model class that have iCollection type.

The question is how can I add them to my serializer?

I tried to write an abstract fabric and create a serializer class using type(), but this approach is too ugly, I suppose there should be much more easier solution.